The #N/A error is preventing sort and filter in Excel 365. The error is from unpopulated cell relating to a VLOOKUP formula at end of current records
I have created a spreadsheet to record medical records for my sheep. I have two VLOOKUP formulae: one for animal number based on animal name; the other for practitioner name based on alpha value.
Google states that errors in the formulae may cause issues when sorting and filtering. These are the only two formulae in the sheet. I am assuming that as most of the sheet is empty pending completion on an-as-and-when basis, that the #N/A in these two cells in these empty records, is upsetting the sorting/filtering. But how do I combine an "if blank" or "if error" formula with a VLOOKUP formula? Screenshots are available.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Can you provide move details about your sheet and formula used, perhaps share a link to your Excel workbook. Also please be more specific with "your issue", simply "Google states" something isn't a real issue that you have.

Manage the #N/A errors using by wrapping VLOOKUP in the IFNA function.
For example, =IFNA(VLOOKUP( ),"") *
* VLOOKUP( ) is a placeholder for your current formula

